# How to get internet with Raspberry pi 3 configured as Access Point

Tags: networking, wifi

I follow these instructions for set my raspberry pi 3 as an access point https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/

It works but now I want to share the connection of my clients connected on the access point for get internet on the raspberry pi.

When I use Ethernet connection I can reach natively internet network so I don't understand why it's not working with wifi in AP mode.

I'm a noobie in network management so I put some command which I hope could help you.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:f4:79:b4  
          inet6 addr: fe80::12a:d36e:817d:73c6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:21726 (21.2 KiB)  TX bytes:21726 (21.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:a1:2c:e1  
          inet addr:172.24.1.1  Bcast:172.24.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5744:c4a:3574:d69c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1768 errors:0 dropped:1522 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:90 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:278297 (271.7 KiB)  TX bytes:17624 (17.2 KiB)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     303    0        0 wlan0
172.24.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

At this moment I had one device connected on the AP which had internet connection.

Comment: You want to use internet via your client with the Raspberry Pi? Why don't you set up your client as an access point and connect to your client with your Raspberry Pi, kind of the opposite of what you are trying to do now.

Comment: Because I would like to use the raspberry as an embedded system which use the clients for getting internet access. Your solution requires that I must reconfigure the raspberry each time I want to use a different client.

Comment: I cannot open the link to the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Will need to either bridge or forward wlan0 and eth0. Your eth0 isn't showing an IPV4 address and isn't showing any traffic. I'd fix that first.

Bridging is easiest...

Add

```
bridge=br0
```

to your hostapd.conf file and reboot. This will automatically create a bridge and add wlan0 to it.

After the network connections come up.
use the command:

```
brctl addif br0 eth0
```

This will add eth0 to the bridge. Whatever connects to the AP should get an IP from the DHCP server on eth0.